# Using Javascript to run a php script to check username

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been trying to build a registeration form for a website I am building. I can do the basics but I want it to check the username availability without reloading the page.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#Username").focusout(function()
        {
            //Check if usernane if available
            var username = $("#Username").val();
            $.post("scripts/check_username.php", {username:  username}, function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'false')
                {
                    alert('Username not available');
                    $("#Username").setCustomValidity("This username is already taken!");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Username available');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="registerForm">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Username</td><td><input id="Username" class='textInput' type='text' name='username' required></td></tr>
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
include 'open_connection.php';
$result = 'true';
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE Username='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result = 'false';
}
echo $result;
?>
```

When I leave the textbox it says username available no matter what. I placed a username "test" in the database... no luck

Please help

Comment: And your question *is*? Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated; you should be using `mysqli_*`.

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to post the problem

Comment: I want to get the value of that textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
$output = 'true';
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE Username='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output = 'false';
}
echo $output;
```

Ans Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Username").focusout(function()
    {
        //Check if usernane if available
        $.post("scripts/check_username.php", {username:  $("#Username").val()}, function(data)
        {

            if(data  =='false')
            {
                    $("#Username").setCustomValidity("This username is already taken!");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Username available');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

By the way, don't use **mysql_*** function, they're deprecated. use Mysqli or PDO. Next thing is you forgot to put semi-colon that the end of your statements !

Comment: That's your connection or your server!

Comment: It was an error with my side, it doesn't work either. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Im still getting username availble when I use "test"

Comment: Use two   variables in php like I did otherwise you get what you get now!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see where you used two variables... sorry to be a pain

Comment: `$output`  and `$result`. Use them like I did!

Answer (score 0):

You specify `$("#Username").value` do you mean to use `$("#Username").val()`?

`$('#Username').value` is probably returning you rubbish which will not exist in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Developer Tools or Firebug?

It would be easy to see where the issue lies if you examined the $.post to check_username.php:

(1) is the correct post request being sent? I think your data object should be `{"username":username}`

(2) is your script responding `true`? or something else? You only know it's not returning false by the way your if statement is structured.

Comment: I'm not talking about your editor/IDE.  I'm talking about looking at the code in action -- in the browser.